# Вывести список товаров у которых максимальная цена в категории

Tags: sql, postgresql

Новичок с SQL..
БД - postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
Id  Name        category    cost
1   apple       fruit       20
2   avocado     fruit       15
3   banana      fruit       20
4   cashew      nut         200
5   chestnut    nut         150
6   strawberry  berry       70
7   raspberry   berry       60
```

нужно вывести список товаров (name) у которых максимальная цена (cost) в категории (category)

Сделал запрос:

```
SELECT distinct category, MAX(cost) FROM my_table GROUP BY category ORDER BY category;
```

но он выводит категорию и максимальную цену и не учитывает одинаковую стоимость, а как сделать чтобы выводил имя и всё учитывал?
Понимаю что нужно сделать подзапрос, вроде такого:

```
SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE cost = (SELECT MAX(cost) FROM my_table GROUP BY category ORDER BY category);
```

но подзапрос должен выводить только одно значение из-за чего там ошибка..

Comment: Стандартно - в CTE нумеровать по группе с нужной сортировкой, вывести записи с первым номером.

Comment: не знал что есть такая штука как CTE. В итоге и правда через неё всё решилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решилось через CTE. Спасибо #Akina за коммент про CTE.

Решение:

```
WITH table_1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT category, MAX(cost) as cost FROM my_table GROUP BY category ORDER BY category)
SELECT name FROM table_1, my_table WHERE my_table.cost = table_1.cost;
```